# How to swap a (log) file that a process has opened with a symlink to another file?

Tags: symlink, lsof

I have two processes that are writing to a log.

`~/app/log/debug.log`

For storing logs, I created a separate disk, mounted at `/mnt/logs/`, it also contains a `/mnt/logs/debug.log` file.

However, I forgot to symlink the `~/app/log/` to `/mnt/logs/` before starting the process. The process then created the `log` dir, the `debug.log` file and started writing to it.

Is it possible to swap out the file that the process is writing to, with a symlink? Without stopping the process?

Comment: Once a program has a file open, it has _that file_ and you can't change that.  Even if you `rm` that directory entry, the file will still exist and that program will still be accessing it.  If you want to get it writing to another file, you will need to stop the existing program and restart it after the rearrangement.

Comment: MAP just to understand your comment, when the `logrotate` is rotating the log file that time it replaces the file with the new one. the process is not stopped. Logrotate is working differently or it has the same thing.

Comment: If he changes the file path in the logrotate configuration with the exact permission and execute the logrotate cron manually will it work.

Comment: But if `logrotate` can do it, so can I, not? What magic is `logrotate` using to "move the file"?